# Convert time in milliseconds back to a timestamp Python?

Tags: python, pandas, time

I have a dataframe like this:

```
 import numpy as np
 import pandas as pd

 df_time   = pd.DataFrame({
'TIMETAG': ['13:52:41.562', '13:52:41.640', '13:52:41.749', '13:52:41.838', 
'13:52:41.948', '13:52:42.048', '13:52:42.138']})
```

Which has been converted to milliseconds with this command:

```
timetag   = pd.to_datetime(df_time['TIMETAG'])
timeit    = timetag.astype('int64')//(10**6)
```

I changed the array `timeit` to a one with an equal spacing (100 milliseconds):

```
timeit_min = np.amin(timeit)
timeit_max = np.amax(timeit)

timerange = np.arange(timeit_min, timeit_max, 100)
```

How can I get back a timestamp - formatted as the one in the `df_time` - from `timerange`?

Comment: you can `apply` the python `datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp` function

Comment: yes but how does it work for an entire array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pandas can handle this case directly

```
pd.to_datetime(timeit,unit='ms')
```

Comment: ValueError: non convertible value 13:52:41.562 with the unit 'ms'

Comment: yeah... that is on the string column. You can apply this to the filtered milliseconds column you called timeit. I explicitly updated the solution.

Comment: I'm sorry, I have one more question: how would you omit the year, month, day and keep just hours:minutes:seconds format?

Comment: date.dt.strftime('%H:%M:%S')

Comment: how would you implement it in this specific example? now it writes: 'DatetimeIndex' object has no attribute 'dt'